# browserify: concatenated browserified files => error _prelude.js vs. loading separate files work

Tags: gruntjs, concatenation, browserify

Running into a problem when concatenating two browserified files (vendor.js and app.js into combined.js)

Loading combined.js in the browser throws the following in _prelude.js :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s}'
```

while loading the browserified files individually works just fine.

What am I missing?
(let me know if you need more config, happy to provide)

Thanks for your help!

In Gruntfile.js:

```
browserify: {
        vendor: {
            src: ['client/requires/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'build/vendor.js',
            options: {
                shim: {
                    jquery: {
                        path: 'client/requires/jquery/js/jquery.js',
                        exports: '$'
                    },
                    underscore: {
                        path: 'client/requires/underscore/js/underscore.js',
                        exports: '_'
                    },
                    backbone: {
                        path: 'client/requires/backbone/js/backbone.js',
                        exports: 'Backbone',
                        depends: {
                            underscore: 'underscore'
                        }
                    },
                    'backbone.marionette': {
                        path: 'client/requires/backbone.marionette/js/backbone.marionette.js',
                        exports: 'Marionette',
                        depends: {
                            jquery: '$',
                            backbone: 'Backbone',
                            underscore: '_'
                        }
                    },
                    eventsource: {
                        path: 'client/requires/eventsource/eventsource.js',
                        exports: 'EventSource'
                    },
                    moment: {
                        path: 'client/requires/moment/moment.js',
                        exports: 'moment'
                    },
                    bootstrap: {
                        path: 'client/requires/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js',
                        exports: null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        app: {
            files: {
                'build/app.js': ['client/src/main.js']
            },
            options: {
                transform: ['node-underscorify'],
                debug: true,
                external: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.marionette', 'eventsource', 'moment', 'bootstrap']
            }
        },
    },

    concat: {
        'build/<%= pkg.name %>.js': ['build/vendor.js', 'build/app.js']
    },
```

Comment: You're not alone, I'm trying to resolve the same issue

Comment: Another instance of the same issue [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583814/browserify-module-is-not-defined

Comment: Adding a semicolon at end of browserified file fixed this issue for me. Submitted this issue on github: https://github.com/substack/browserify-website/issues/26

Comment: having same issue with gulp, loading larvels `bootstrap.js`, an AdminLTE implementation, and `app.js` all i the same file.  I have tried using `gulp-order` as well, to no avail, its definitely when i try to put them all on the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some initial investigation and there appears to be a definite problem with the preamble.    I've raised an issue with the grunt-browserify maintainers so lets see what comes of that.

For now I am concatenating a file between vendor.js and app.js as a way to fix the preamble as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
concat: {
        'build/<%= pkg.name %>.js': ['build/vendor.js', 'client/src/fix_browserify', 'build/app.js']
    },
```

**fix_browserify**

```
require=
```

Note there is no carriage return or linefeed in the above file

I am unsure if there will be any unintended consequences of defining `require` twice but it appears to be working in my limited use.  If you have more than just one app bundle then you would similarly need to interleave concatenation of the `fix_browserify` file before each of the bundles.

If I become aware of any better solutions I'll update this answer.

**UPDATE**

I ended up ditching grunt/browserify after looking at how browerify worked and just went with brunch which was far easier to setup and also does much faster rebuilds when things change. Whilst not a grunt replacement it builds everything I need.

Answer (score 2):

### Quick solution

We fixed this error by ensuring that the JS bundle in each file ended with a semi-colon, like [Keven Wang mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514884/browserify-concatenated-browserified-files-error-prelude-js-vs-loading-sep#comment39795587_21514884), before being concatenated.

### More information

It seems like as of writing, Browserify omits the semi-colon (possibly due to [this issue](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify/issues/185)) **if you have enabled generating source maps** (controlled by `debug` option). If we don't provide this option, Browserify adds the semi-colon and there are no errors after concatenating.

There seem to be issues caused by whatever the default behaviour is—omitting or appending the semi-colon (see [this issue](https://github.com/substack/browser-pack/issues/36)—sometimes you want to wrap the output in an expression, so don't want the semi-colon). It depends heavily on your build pipeline too, as we had no errors in another project with a slightly different build process that was running the output through Grunt's `uglify` task, stripping the source maps, and adding the semi-colon at the end.

I think Andrew's solution of adding a spacer file is unnecessarily hacky, and there are better solutions available to ensure the output is as you expect (i.e. with semi-colons at the end) before concatenating the bundles.

Comment: ensuring the last uncommented js line ended in a semicolon didn't fix this in my case (using gulp). The only solution so far is to not concatenate, and load them separately.