# Browserify "module is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am new to browserify. I tried the code below and got `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` when loading my web page. Everything is pretty plain and simple so not sure what I am doing wrong:

chronoOpenList.js:

```
module.exports = function getChronoOpenList() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET", "api/nextrequestdue/", true);
    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200) {
            var jsonText =  xml.responseText;
            parseChronoAndBuildElements(jsonText);
        }
    }
    xml.send(null);
}
```

main.js:

```
var getChronoOpenList = require('./chronoOpenList');
getChronoOpenList();
```

html:

```
<script style="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bundle.js' %}"></script>
```

The command to browserify:

```
one@chat-dash /home/git/recognizer/recognizer_project/static/js $ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js main.js -o bundle.js
```

The bundle.js:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = function getChronoOpenList() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET", "api/nextrequestdue/", true);
    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200) {
            var jsonText =  xml.responseText;
            parseChronoAndBuildElements(jsonText);
        }
    }
    xml.send(null);
}

....
},{"./chronoOpenList":1}]},{},[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `parseChronoAndBuildElements` is not defined in the scope of your `getChronoOpenList` function.

You need to define `parseChronoAndBuildElements` in that scope, like this:

chronoOpenList.js:

```
var parseChronoAndBuildElements = require('./parseChronoAndBuildElements.js');

module.exports = function getChronoOpenList() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("GET", "api/nextrequestdue/", true);
    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200) {
            var jsonText =  xml.responseText;
            parseChronoAndBuildElements(jsonText);
        }
    }
    xml.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to:

```
var parseChronoAndBuildElements = window.parseChronoAndBuildElements;
```